# Add comma to days just like profile views

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Please add a comma to the value of visits in days like you did in the profile views in the same screen shot:

[image]

Comment: lucky you didn't click the text there..or you'd be complaining about the jQuery date picker repurposed to show the visited days :p

Comment: Discussion or feature request? Imho there's not much to discuss, it's a reasonable UI improvement, I don't expect someone will disagree.

Comment: please remove one in the first place (and other places where it's used) as it is confusing for people from locales where comma is used instead of decimal point. Or may be at least use user locale

Comment: Also, *just* adding a comma there can make that line of text confusing: For example: 
"visited 2,300 days, 2 consecutive". If the `,` is added, it might be a good idea to use `;` as the separator between "days" and the "# consecutive".

Comment: Good idea, but it should be tagged as `[feature-request]` and like @Makyen already mentioned, replace the current comma as separator

Comment: @Makyen _The 22nd General Conference on Weights and Measures declared in 2003 that "the symbol for the decimal marker shall be either the point on the line or the comma on the line". It further reaffirmed that "**numbers may be divided in groups of three in order to facilitate reading; neither dots nor commas are ever inserted in the spaces between groups**"_ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Current_standards))

Comment: @Cœur You got it, best solution is to use international convention, this number is supposed to be divided like so : "visited 2 330 days, 2 consecutive"

Comment: @Cœur I'm wondering why your comment was addressed to me. If what you've stated is what you really want, then it needs to be it's own feature request/discussion, as the implementation is *much further* reaching than this discussion. IMO, what should be implemented as a separator here is whatever matches the way that such numbers are displayed across the entire site. What you've advocated is, effectively, changing that representation throughout the site, as having that representation, or any representation here, which does not match is the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, just noticed every number on Stack community has it's thousand separated by a coma, perhaps it shall be the same with visited number. Anyway, the css haven't been applied on it. Starting with that would be logical.

Comment: @Makyen, I would be unhappy to see a semicolon. It feels like advocating a wrong (a semicolon) to cancel another wrong (a comma). I've seen this happening many times in code, and I prefer when it's solved at its root (adopting International System of Units).

Comment: @Cœur When posted as an answer, this attitude (which I share) seems to have gathered quick DVs.

Comment: Coming from the UK I much prefer the comma delimited one to the space delimited one. This isn't a "standard" I have seen followed much. Would it be possible to display numbers in the format relevant to the users locale?

Comment: If you adding a comma to the number of days visited, why not request a comma for the number of *consecutive* days as well?

Comment: Yep I'm on 1,302 consecutive and see no comma. Though tbh I don't really miss it when the number is only 4 digits long.

Answer (score 10):

### I object!

Commas should not be used for place value notation at all! In parts of Western Europe a comma is used as the decimal separator. It is confusing. Most of all, it is wrong.

This objection is summed up quite nicely by [Cœur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1033581):

> *The 22nd General Conference on Weights and Measures declared in 2003 that "the symbol for the decimal marker shall be either the point on the line or the comma on the line". It further reaffirmed that **"numbers may be divided in groups of three in order to facilitate reading; neither dots nor commas are ever inserted in the spaces between groups"*** ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Current_standards)) – [source](/q/360357/5223757#comment538389_360357)

Considering that Stack Exchange currently uses the correct, unambiguous date standard for the tooltip on post times, why should ordinary numbers be any different? ([Relevant](https://xkcd.com/1179/) [xkcds](https://xkcd.com/927/).)

If this is changed at all, please either make it correct as per the international standard, or add regionalisation support. (I know which one will take the least dev time.)

Comment: Wow. Three downvotes in 3 minutes. I'll remove the cat.

Comment: I *totally* see where you're coming from though, but surely there's a way to do locale-centric number formatting here...  (Also, my reputation shows up with a comma in it.  I'm not convinced other locales *don't* show the comma.)

Comment: @Makoto There's a way, but I don't think it's implemented. Afaik there's no localisation _at all_.

Comment: While there certainly is a case to not use commas for place value notation, it's already implemented in multiple places in the site (like Makoto noted for reputation, but also for number of posts, answers, and on many more places). A uniform design is more important imo. If you want SO to use a proper separator, start a separate feature request to change it everywhere, but imo half/half (or rather on one place/everywhere else) is worse than everywhere wrong.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That is a very good point. However, this _is_ a live system, so changes won't be rolled out all at once regardless.